# How do I replace the default qualifier with whitespace in SSRS by editing the rsreportserver.config file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I have an end user that needs double quotes around one text field with the remainder of the report exported in csv format while pipe delimited and without any headers. I have used the below code inserted into the rsreportserver.config to achieve all of this. The " are added where expected using a calculated field.

The problem: Having " in the output causes extra " to be added on export to csv since it is the default qualifier. I tried changing the qualifier to / instead. This succeeded, but it still treated the " as the default qualifier and placed extra / into the file. The end user can not handle any extra visible qualifier.

I tried using the xml preserve command as illustrated for the FieldDelimiter here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365.aspx but this returned to the default behavior of inserting an extra ". Does anyone have some insight into this?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
        <Extension Name="PIPE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
            <OverrideNames>
                <Name Language="en-US">PIPE Delimited CSV</Name>
            </OverrideNames>
            <Configuration>
              <DeviceInfo>
                <FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter>
                <NoHeader>True</NoHeader>
                <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
                <Qualifier xml:space="preserve"> </Qualifier>
              </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made multiple attempts with different options at this. I have conversed with several more experienced programers and one SQL MCM. The consensus I have come to is that there is no way to have both pipe delimitated and a single set of " in a text field while exporting to excel from SSRS.

It is recommended to use SSIS or SSMS to achieve such results.